# Define system forward dynamics with sympy

Tags: mobile-robot, dynamics, robot-model

I would like to model the dynamics of a robot via the usual discretized system of equations

$$
x_{k+1} = f(x_k, u_k) \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^{n_x}, \quad f:\mathbb{R}^{n_x}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_u} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_x}
$$

via `sympy` python package, but in the documentation there are only examples of scalar functions $f:\mathbb{R}^{n_x}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_u} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Are there any shortcuts besides defining a `sympy.Matrix` of functions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question why you can't represent the system of equations using scalar functions.

A system of equations is a set of scalar functions where the solution is the intersecting point(s) between the functions. Therefore, you can model and solve them using sympy.

possible approached can be found [here](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/guides/solving/solve-system-of-equations-algebraically.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547657/how-can-i-solve-system-of-linear-equations-in-sympy). Maybe one of the links would help you with your task.